# $\cup_{i=1}^n [\frac 1n , 1] = ]0,1] $??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was just confused, wheater $\cup_{i=1}^n [\frac 1n, 1] = ]0,1]$ is.
I also thought that it might be [0,1] but I think that is not true.

Cheers

Comment: For each $n \ge 1$, $\frac 1n \ne 0$; thus, $0$ is not included into $[\frac 1n, 1]$.

Comment: What does $]0,1]$ mean? Is that supposed to be $(0,1]$? Or is this other notation common?

Comment: this is the notation in use in France, for example.

Comment: show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{n},1)=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty[\frac{1}{n},1)$ Hence LHS is union of open sets so it must be open

Comment: @mookid That's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\bigcup [1/n,1] \subset (0,1]$$

indeed, for each $n$,
$[1/n,1] \subset (0,1]$.

> $$\bigcup [1/n,1] \supset (0,1]$$

let $r\in (0,1]$. Then for $n$ big enough,
$nr>1$ hence $r>1/n$ and $r\in (1/n, \infty)$. As $r\le 1$, 
$r\in (1/n, \infty)\cap (-\infty,1] = (1/n, 1]\subset [1/n,1] $.

Eventually, $r\in \bigcup [1/n,1]$.